# Solr 4.9: Server at http://localhost:80/solr sent back a redirect (302)

Tags: tomcat, solr

I am a newbie to Solr. I have indexed content on Solr and able to query it on Solr dashboard (http://localhost/solr/#/index1/query). I have deployed Solr in a web application via tomcat 7.0.96. The Solr dashboard is working fine and giving me the output of my queries, but when I do a search on the web application, I am getting the below error:

```
Server at http://localhost:80/solr sent back a redirect (302).
```

In my web application, I have tested two URLs:

```
protected String solrServerURL = "http://localhost/solr/index1";
or
protected String solrServerURL ="http://localhost/solr/#/index1";
```

Both of these are giving me the redirect error.

What does it mean? I tried to look for it online but didn't find anything helpful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your web application's HTTP library know how to follow a redirect? Not sure how you are currently querying, but you should be querying your collection using `/solr/index1/select?q=...etc` instead of `/solr/#/index1/query` (from the web app).

Comment: Well, http://localhost/solr/#/index1/query this url points to apache solr dashboard where I can do query see logging etc. My problem is when trying to connect to solr using webapp, give me back the redirect message "Server at http://localhost:80/solr sent back a redirect (302)." So I would like to you know if anyone has seen this error before.

Comment: What URL are you using to query Solr from the web application? Just the path is fine.

Comment: I have set the path in core.properties to my solrdata directory

Comment: The question is what URL you're using in your application; not in your Solr configuration. The redirect happens because you're using a URL without `/` at the end and the httpd redirects to a URL _with_ `/`. Your application probably expects the URL to be in the format `http://localhost:80/solr/index1` - i.e. with the core identifier present.

Comment: This can be tricky. The URL with the # (like `localhost/solr/#/index1/query`) that you use in the Solr admin **is not the same** that you use to query Solr directly via an app, for that you need what Matt suggested `localhost/solr/index1/select`)

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh and Hector In my web application, I have tried using 2 URLs http://localhost/solr/index1 and http://localhost/solr/#/index1. Both of these URLs are giving me the redirect error.

Comment: @HectorCorrea I have updated my question. Sorry I wasn't clear earlier.

Comment: @Rose I would suggest that you run a query via the Query screen (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/query-screen.html), grab the URL that it shows ( `http://127.0.0.1:7574/solr/films/select?indent...` in the example), and go to that URL in your browser, it should show you the result set in XML/JSON. If that works, use that URL in your program.

Comment: The one with the "#" will not work from your program, that URL is something that the Solr Admin interprets and knows how to handle, but it is specific to that web page only. The one without the "#" should work, but it might need some tweaking.

Comment: Do you have an redirect-http-to-https rule active on that server? Does the same URL work in your browser? Does the `Network` tab in your browser's development tools show the request going to a different service?